# Smooth Scroll Up and Down to Multiple Anchors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to Web Dev and I want to make a website that can scroll-up and down-to multiple anchors using the side navigation bar.

This is my html code,

```
<body>
 <div id="mySideDiv" class="divAnimate">
  <p id="head">HYUNJAE<br>WOO</p>
  <div class="side"><a href="#home">HOME</a></div>
  <div class="side"><a href="#portfolio">PORTFOLIO</a></div>
  <div class="side"><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></div>
  <div class="side"><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></div>
 </div>

 <div class="mid-cont homePage" id="main">
  <article class="panel"><a id="home"></a>
   <p> Welcome to My Website </p>
   ...
  </article>

  <article class="panel"><a id="portfolio"></a>
   <p> PORTFORLIO </p><br>
   ...
  </article>

  <article class="panel"><a id="contact"></a>
   <p> CONTACT </p><br>
   ...
</article>

<article class="panel"><a id="about"></a>
  <p> ABOUT </p><br>
  ...
</article>
```

I have this working with just  tag, but I want the smooth transition/scroll to the anchor every time I click on the side bar(my side bar is fixed in position). I have searched through the internet and found few answers using jQuery or javascript, but they ONLY WORKED WHEN IT WAS TOP-TO-BOTTOM SCROLL. Whenever I tried to go from CONTACT up to PORTFOLIO, it would place the screen somewhere between HOME and PORTFOLIO. I feel like the answer is going to be very obvious, but I can't figure out why...Please help me.

Comment: One of these links may solve your problem:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717527/smooth-scrolling-when-clicking-an-anchor-link

Comment: something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571656/difference-between-current-position-and-scrolled-position-with-jquery/34572021#34572021 ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19012631/3148672) answer?
Your html code will be:

```
<div class="side"><a href="#home" onclick="SmoothScroll()">HOME</a></div>

function SmoothScroll() {
    e.preventDefault();
    var target = $(this).attr("href");
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(""+target).offset().top
    }, 2000);}
```

Comment: did you check my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code for such functionality:

```
$(".same-page-links").on("click", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var target = $(this).attr("href");
  if( $(""+target).length )
  {
    var targetOffset = $(""+target).offset().top;
    $("html, body").animate({"scrollTop": targetOffset}, 500);
  }
});//click
```

Here, I have assumed that all such links have a class "same-page-links".
On click of such links, you can grab the target element's id from their `href` attribute or any other attribute. Once you have that, you simply need to know the `offset().top`  of that element and scroll to that offset using jQuery [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) method.

One more thing, instead of creating empty `a` elements to contain your target id's, you should assign those id's to those articles themselves. e.g.
instead of

```
<article class="panel"><a id="about"></a>
```

you should do this

```
<article id="about" class="panel">
```